# How to omit empty Model errors in tune.svm()?

Tags: svm

I’am trying to use the tune.svm-function and since I don’t really know which parameters will produce a good model (as training data will be picked by a user) I need to cover a wide range of values. Currently I've got this behavior

`tune(svm, value ~ . , data= data_l, ranges=list(cost = 10^(0:5), epsilon = 10^(-1:0)))`

```
Parameter tuning of ‘svm’:
- sampling method: 10-fold cross validation 
- best parameters:
 cost epsilon
  100     0.1
- best performance: 277.5491
```

and

```
tune(svm, value ~ . , data= data_l, ranges=list(cost = 10^(0:5), epsilon = 10^(-1:1)))
Error in predict.svm(ret, xhold, decision.values = TRUE) : Model is empty!
```

(Difference in the highest value of epsilon)

I know that svm won’t work with epsilon =10 but my intuition for this tuning function would be, that it can handle parameters that will not produce a model. 
Why wouldn't it pick the models that could be generated?
Is there an “easy” way to omit this error-behavior? (I tried tryCatch(tune()) and a lot of other stuff I found, but I guess I would have to dig deep into the tune/svm/predict-codes which doesn’t sound “easy” anymore)

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of the "Model is empty!" error is that it indicates a [singular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix) training matrix was fed into the SVM. See Salvy's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27024267/3632747) to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24163316/model-is-empty-svm-in-e1071-package) related post and [Oldrich Kruza](http://mailto:sixtease@gmail.com)'s related [message](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2007-March/127853.html) in the R mailing list.