# SVM Error in R (Error in predict.svm(ret, xhold, decision.values = TRUE) : Model is empty!)

Tags: r, machine-learning, svm

I am running a regression model using SMV code below:

```
tuned_m<- tune(svm, Lanes_Cleared_Duration~Main_Street+Blocked_Lanes+Total_Vehicle_Count+Tractor_Trailer_Count+Weather_Winter_Storm+Weather_Rain+Injuries_Count+
                 Accident_Overturned_Car+Fatalities_Count+Speed+Total_Volume+Occupancy+PredictedClass, data = training,
               ranges = list(epsilon=seq(0,2,0.1), cost=2^(2:7)))
svm_model_Regression_1<- tuned_m$best.model
saveRDS(svm_model_Regression_1, "svm_model_Regression_1.rds")
```

The training data is:

```
training = structure(list(Main_Street = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L), levels = c("64", "70", "270"), class = "factor"), 
    Blocked_Lanes = c(3L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 5L, 4L), 
    Total_Vehicle_Count = c(2L, 2L, 1L, 7L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 
    2L), Tractor_Trailer_Count = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L), Weather_Winter_Storm = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), 
    Weather_Rain = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L), levels = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), Injuries_Count = c(0L, 
    3L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L), Accident_Overturned_Car = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("No", "Yes"
    ), class = "factor"), Fatalities_Count = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), Speed = c(12L, 61L, 38L, 4L, 68L, 
    4L, 28L, 4L, 61L, 11L), Total_Volume = c(61.5, 6.7, 4.7, 
    36.7, 106, 22, 102, 22, 54, 45.5), Occupancy = c(30, 0.6, 
    0.5, 65.9, 5.3, 30.5, 14.5, 30.5, 5.1, 21.2), Lanes_Cleared_Duration = c(144L, 
    263L, 135L, 136L, 31L, 172L, 31L, 172L, 47L, 49L), Cluster = structure(c(3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("1", "2", 
    "3"), class = "factor"), PredictedClass = structure(c(3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("1", "2", 
    "3"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

The same works perfectly for this problem unless I do a little change in the breaks of PredictedClass and it results in the following error:

```
Error in predict.svm(ret, xhold, decision.values = TRUE) : 
  Model is empty!
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24163316/model-is-empty-svm-in-e1071-package) Post have the same question but the answer does not help solving my problem.